# Basic get request, not returning cookies

Tags: python

I am doing a simple get request to get a website cookies:

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as s:

    session = requests.Session()

    response = session.get("http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/index.html")
    ncooks = session.cookies.get_dict()
    print(ncooks)
```

But, when the ncooks gets returned it is empty {}

Why is this? How can I solve this problem to get the cookies for the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works, the website you're using just doesn't set a cookie. Try with http://nytimes.com, the dict won't be empty.

Unrelated, but you're creating an unnecessary extra Session object; it should look like this:

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as s:
    response = s.get("http://nytimes.com")
    cooks = s.cookies.get_dict()
    print(cooks)
```